# Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, server-setup

I have site in Magento 2.2.

But after move site one server to another server it's stopped working.

Show me below error in **exception.log** file.

```
[2019-06-13 10:13:36] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/elitemm5/public_html/britanica/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 394 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Warning: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/elitemm5/public_html/britanica/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 394 at /home/elitemm5/public_html/britanica/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

Any type of help will be appreciated.

Thanks!